# Cannot add same key to dictionary more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<ServiceTicket> troubletickets = db.ServiceTickets.Include(t => t.Company).Include(t => t.UserProfile);
var ticketGroups = new Dictionary<string, List<ServiceTicket>>();

ticketGroups = troubletickets
                .GroupBy(o => o.DueDate).ToDictionary(
                    group => {
                        var firstOrDefault = @group.FirstOrDefault();
                        return firstOrDefault != null
                            ? firstOrDefault.DueDate.HasValue
                                ? firstOrDefault.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
                                : ""
                            : "";
                    },
                    group => group.ToList()
                ).OrderBy(g => g.Key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);
```

The error that I am getting is: 'An item with the same key has already been added.' This is because the DueDate value is occasionally repeated. My question is how can I keep the key from being added if it already exists in the dictionary?

Comment: Rather than using [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), iterate through the items in the query and build the dictionary yourself.  You can even make your own enumerable extension `ToDictionaryWithDuplicatedKeys()`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can also use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - adding a duplicate key is possible, but the collection contains the item only once. But it would be probably easier to apply Distinct as already suggested.

Comment: Well, I am trying to group my tickets by date. E.g. I want to group all tickets by the date 10/20/2014. So, I want to maintain the tickets within that group. I tried .GroupBy(o => o.DueDate).Distinct().ToDictionary()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are grouping by one value (the `DueDate` value), but using a different value as the dictionary key.

Can you not just use the custom code for grouping instead?

```
ticketGroups = troubletickets
                .GroupBy(o => o.DueDate.HasValue
                                ? o.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
                                : "")
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Note that I took our the superfluous `OrderBy` and second `ToDictionary` call - I assumed you were trying to "order" the dictionary which won't work as a plain dictionary is not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You get duplicate keys because there are two ways to get an empty string as key, either an empty group, or an empty date. The duplicate will always be the empty string. I wonder if you really intended to get an empty string as key when the group is empty. Anyway, it's not necessary, you can always filter empty groups later.

It's easier to group by date (including null) first through the database engine and then apply string formatting in memory:

```
IQueryable<ServiceTicket> troubletickets = db.ServiceTickets
                                             .Include(t => t.Company)
                                             .Include(t => t.UserProfile);

Dictionary<string, List<ServiceTicket>> ticketGroups = 
                troubletickets
               .GroupBy(ticket => ticket.DueDate)
               .AsEnumerable() // Continue in memory
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.HasValue 
                                        ? g.Key.Value.ToShortDateString() 
                                        : string.Empty,
                                  g => g.Select(ticket => ticket));
```

Now the grouping is by the `Key` value, not by the `First` element in the group. The `Key` is never null, it's always a `Nullable<DateTime>`, with or without a value.

Side note: you'll notice that EF will not generate a SQL `group by` statement, that's because the SQL statement is "destructive": it only returns grouped columns and aggregate data, not the individual records that a LINQ `GroupBy` *does* return. For this reason, the generated SQL is pretty bloated and it *may* enhance performance if you place the `AsEnumerable` before the `.GroupBy`.